# How can I avoid overflowing R_SPARC_13 relocations when writing SPARC assembly?

Tags: programming, assembly

For fun I'm trying to create an assembly program for Sun Solaris on SPARC.  I'm emulating the system with QEMU.

My test assembles fine, yet linking fails with "relocation error: R_SPARC_13". Googling that error did not help at all.

```
        .section        ".text"
        .global main
        .type   main,@function

        .align  16
main:
        mov     4,%g1                   ! 4 is SYS_write
        mov     1,%o0   ! 1 is stdout
        mov     test,%o1        ! pointer to buffer
        mov     6,%o2   ! length
        ta      8

        mov     1,%g1                   ! 1 is SYS_exit
        clr     %o0                     ! return status is 0
        ta      8

test:   .asciz "hallo\n"
```

I assembled it with:

```
as test.s
ld a.out -o test
```

which gives:

```
ld: fatal: relocation error: R_SPARC_13:
ld: fatal:  file a.out: 
ld: fatal:  symbol <unknown>: 
ld: fatal:  value 0x103b0 does not fit
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: found that "mov test,%o1" should be "set test,%o1". Because set handles the large pointer value. But I don't understand why then e.g.

```
        JMP bla
        nop
    bla:
        ...
```

also still gives that R_SPARC_13 error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

SPARC instructions are 32-bit in size, so you cannot load a 32-bit pointer as an immediate in one instruction.  This is typical of any RISC architecture.  The alternatives are to split the immediate value across multiple instructions and logical-OR them, or load indirectly from memory.

The smallest change you can make to make it work as intended is to replace the `mov` with:

```
sethi %hi(test), %l0
or %l0, %lo(test), %o1
```

That will emit two relocation records in the object file, `R_SPARC_HI22` and `R_SPARC_LO10` which combine to cover an entire 32-bit pointer value, which are fixed-up by the linker.

Testing:

```
sparc-unknown-linux-gnu-as --32 -o test.o test.s
sparc-unknown-linux-gnu-ld -melf32_sparc -o test test.o
qemu-sparc -strace ./test

2701656 write(1,0x10084,6)hallo
 = 6
2701656 exit(0)
```

Comment: Strange that this doesn't generate a compile-time error.

Comment: @PMF It is possible that you're going to use this with a custom linker script that'll ensure that `test` is small enough to fit into the low 13 bits of a register.The assembler therefore can't error, because it may work, depending on your linker settings, but the linker will give you the `R_SPARC_13` error to tell you you've got it wrong at compile time.

Answer (score 7):

Try `B bla` rather than `JMP bla`.  As I understand it, `JMP bla` is a synthetic instruction that translates to `JMPL bla, %g0` and you have the same large point problem.  (Unfortunately, I do not know why the `JMPL` construct fails.)